# Downgrade from kernel 5 to Kernel 4

Tags: debian, ubuntu, kernel

What's the best and fastest way to downgrade Ubuntu from kernel 5 to Kernel 4?

Comment: That is a very risky and tricky thing to do. Just installing an older kernel might break many dependencies of currently installed programs. You would have to install the old kernel and find all programs that depend on the newer kernel, then install the old version of those. If you are lucky, though, you might still have the old kernels as boot options - so check that in the first place.

Comment: @Fiximan no, unless the OP is writing 5.x-specific XDP/eBPF programs, the only requirement will be [systemd’s dependency on a 4.2 or later kernel](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/README) for unified cgroup hierarchy support.

Comment: @StephenKitt I assume, you are talking about a bootable system, where I was referring to desktop utilities that might be in use. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @Fiximan apart from kernel-specific tools, I don’t think there are any desktop utilities which *require* a 5.x kernel. Applications’ interface to the kernel is the C library, and the current GNU C library only requires kernel 3.2 or later. (New kernels provide some new features, but their availability or otherwise shouldn’t *break* applications.)

Comment: @Fiximan I’m not saying it’s a good idea to downgrade the kernel, because the Ubuntu developers have tested 19.04 and 19.10 with 5.x kernels, and running older kernels isn’t a good idea from a security perspective; but the consequences of downgrading aren’t as dire as your comment suggests. (The 4.x-to-5.x change is cosmetic only anyway, so the considerations are the same as when downgrading 4.19 to 4.18 for example.)

Comment: @StephenKitt Thanks for the clarification. I mostly encountered kernel problems with drivers - namely WiFi-cards and touchpads - which even forced me to use backports (I run Debian where possible) in some cases. But I might indeed have overestimated the severity of the issue.

Comment: @Fiximan right, driver support certainly changes from one kernel version to another (and hopefully gets better with newer kernels)!

Answer (score 1):

The best solution was to install kernel 4.x then boot ubuntu from that kernel.
It wasn't risky at all.

Thanks!